# rpcinfo shows service running while it is disabled

Tags: solaris

I am trying to shutdown some RPC services on my solaris servers. I am getting some issues.

host = SERVER

need to disable two rpc services:

RPC Calendar Service cmsd Available (rpc.cmsd)
and,
RPC snmpxdmid

```
RPC Calendar Service cmsd Available (rpc.cmsd)
root@SERVER # rpcinfo -p | grep 100068
    100068    2   udp  32777
    100068    3   udp  32777
    100068    4   udp  32777
    100068    5   udp  32777
    100068    2   tcp  45108
    100068    3   tcp  45108
    100068    4   tcp  45108
    100068    5   tcp  45108

root@SERVER # svcs -a|grep -i cal
legacy_run     2012     lrc:/etc/rc2_d/S94ncalogd
online         2012     svc:/network/physical:default
online         2012     svc:/system/device/local:default
online         2012     svc:/network/ipsec/ipsecalgs:default
online         2012     svc:/system/filesystem/local:default
online         2012     svc:/application/graphical-login/cde-login:default
online         2015     svc:/network/rpc/cde-calendar-manager:default

root@SERVER # ps -ef|grep rpc
  daemon   368     1   0   Nov 06 ?           0:01 /usr/sbin/rpcbind
  daemon  5494  5488   0   Dec 11 ?           0:00 /usr/dt/bin/rpc.cmsd
    root  2652  2647   0   Dec 11 ?           0:00 /usr/openwin/bin/rpc.ttdbserverd
    root  2647   405   0   Dec 11 ?           0:00 /bin/sh /lib/svc/method/rpc-ttdbserverd
    root  5488   405   0   Dec 11 ?           0:00 /bin/sh /lib/svc/method/rpc-cmsd
    root  5485   405   0   Dec 11 ?           0:00 /usr/lib/netsvc/rstat/rpc.rstatd
    root 11260  9261   0 18:21:48 pts/1       0:00 grep rpc
root@SERVER # 

root@SERVER # netstat -na|grep 32777
      *.32777                             Idle
root@SERVER # netstat -na|grep 45108
      *.45108              *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN
root@SERVER # 



RPC snmpxdmid
root@SERVER # rpcinfo -p | grep 100249
    100249    1   udp  32785
    100249    1   tcp  32777

root@SERVER # svcs -a|grep snmp
disabled       21:47:13 svc:/application/management/snmpdx:default

root@SERVER # ps -ef| grep -i snmpdx
    root 11007  9261   0 18:21:30 pts/1       0:00 grep -i snmpdx
root@SERVER # 

root@SERVER # netstat -na|grep 32777
      *.32777                             Idle
root@SERVER # netstat -na|grep 32785
root@SERVER #
```

(for snmpxdmid), the process was running first, so i disabled the service and then process went away and also the listing from "rpcinfo -p" went away, but now it has come back (see the open port in netstat). How can i disable and stop it forever????

=========================

for both these rpc services i do not see any entry in /etc/inetd.conf, how can i disable and stop them?

```
root@SERVER # grep -i rpc /etc/inetd.conf
100235/1 tli rpc/ticotsord wait root /usr/lib/fs/cachefs/cachefsd cachefsd
root@SERVER # 

root@SERVER # uname -a
SunOS SERVER 5.10 Generic_147441-09 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

thank you.

Comment: how did you disable it?

Comment: also, you appear to have 3 services in the Q: cmsd, snmpx, and dmi

Comment: using svcadm command: svcadm disable .....

Comment: {# svcadm disable svc:/network/rpc/cde-calendar-manager
# svcadm disable svc:/application/management/dmi:default}

Comment: but the ports are open in rpcinfo -p. how??? an dhow to shut them down???

Comment: Have you tried `inetadm -d` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see a ptree of 5488 to verify that inetd/SMF is starting the process as `svcadm disable` should have stopped the service.  Most likely SMF did start it since the svc method is being called.  My thought here being that perhaps a legacy start script was starting it.

Memory is that some of the older Solaris update releases did initially still have services being started out of the legacy run levels; and that later patches started moving things over to SMF, but not always cleaning out the legacy start/stop scripts.  Possible patch issue?

Have you looked in the services log in /var/svc/log?
Any existing services that are having issues?   `svcs -xv`

I'm also curious as to why the calendar service started on Dec 11 which is after the Nov 6 date that the rpc service started.  So perhaps SMF stopped it, but something else or someone re-spawned it?

There does not appear to be a dedicated pkg for calendar to remove, but you could always lock down, or outright remove the binary.

Comment: i have now deleted the service vby:  rpcinfo -d 100249    1